# learning how to use xe:dominoViewEntriesTreeNode

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I realized my question was too vague on adding navigation items dynamically, so I am rewriting the question.

I have discovered the xe:dominoViewEntriesTreeNode control from the xpages. I think I can use this to add navigation items to the navigator control based on entries in the view.

I am struggling to find very much in the way of documentation or resources that break down how to do that. Can anybody to me to a good reference or example code?

Comment: Are you using the Extention Library?

Comment: Yes, I am using the extension library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dominoViewListTreeNode to build a menu based on views in a database (and not documents in those views).

Here is an example of using xe:dominoViewListTreeNode to dynamically build a menu based on all views called "Test*" (using regex in the filter property). When selecting a menu item from the menu, the name of the view is submitted to the server (using EL notation for the viewEntry.getName() method).

The example also contains an onItemClick event handler that "catches" the name of the view as the submitted value and stores this in a sessionScope variable. The event handler then redirects to a views.xsp XPage that could contain a Dynamic View Panel control where you could use the sessionScope variable to control what view to show.

The sessionScope variable is also used to mark the selected menu item as "selected".

```
<xe:navigator id="navigator1">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:dominoViewListTreeNode filter="Test.*" submitValue="#{viewEntry.name}" var="viewEntry">
            <xe:this.selected><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewEntry.getName() == sessionScope.clickedView}]]></xe:this.selected>
        </xe:dominoViewListTreeNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>

    <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
         <xp:this.action>
           <![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.clickedView = context.getSubmittedValue();
         context.redirectToPage("views.xsp");}]]>
         </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>

</xe:navigator>
```

Instead of the onItemClick method to redirect to an XPage, you could compute the href property of xe:dominoViewListTreeNode to return the name of an XPage.

I have a short presentation called "[XPages Extension Library - Create an app in 1 hour (almost)](http://www.slideshare.net/perlausten/xpages-extension-library-create-an-app-in-1-hour-almost)" that presents this technique (and other techniques).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an area on your page carrying the navigation items, e.g. links to some pages with link texts?
I would then use a repeat control with a datasource/javascript source that returns the document item values from your profile document or something.
If you are not into repeat controls then you should consider to read this: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_repeat_controls
On this page there is also a sample dealing with a profile document.

By the way: using profile documents was always a crutch, so consider to youse "normal" config documents instead.

Comment: Ok then, my answer doesn't make any sense at all after the revision of your question ;-)